# Most efficient approach of update a one-to-many table

Tags: database, performance

Assume I have a table named bookLibrary in which the unique id of a book is linked to a number of libraries (by their unique id). If you receive an update for a book in the form of an array of the libraries in which a book is found, what is the most efficient approach to update the bookLibrary table.

Currently, I just delete all the rows that relate to the book and add a new relationship (row) for each library in the array that I receive. This seems a bit drastic, but it does the job and it makes sure that there are no duplicate rows in the table.

An alternative approach would be to fetch all the rows for a book and take a look at each row, that is, (1) is the row still valid (is the book still in library x), (2) what rows need to be inserted (have new libraries been added for book x), and (3) which rows remain unaltered.

It's a trivial problem with an easy solution, but a problem like this makes me often wonder about efficiency and I also want to make sure that annoying bugs (like duplicate rows) are avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I had the same problem in a recent app I was working on. My solution was the same as yours, deleting all references and then adding all the rows relevant rows back into the table. (it seems drastic to me too) Alternatively, though it is easy to avoid duplicates by checking to see if the combination already exists before inserting, it is much harder to efficiently find which rows are still valid to remove the invalid ones

Comment: Add the unique index and then you can save yourself the anxiety of duplicates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either approach will work.  I would opt for the 'delete then reinsert' option unless there was a proven performance bottleneck with that approach, as its simpler from the server perspective.  Also, there is no guarantee that loading the rows and doing server side comparisons would be any better, since you need to load the rows, do the in-code calculations, then resave up to n rows.

So to answer your question, you would need to do some profiling to see how the approaches stack up.  A lot would depend on the number of rows, the number of columns in the rows, the sql involved, and possibly how the sql statements are sent to the server.

With respect to reliability, it is possible to mitigate errors with either approach via extensive tests.  I think the 'delete then reinsert' approach is also simpler to test.